How to pass mode config to AzureOpenAIEmbeddings() to create embeddings model
I'm trying to use Azure openai deployment to generate embeddings and store them in Redis vectorDB. I created the embeddings model as follow and pass the model_config (like embedding_ctx_length, generation_max_tokens, allowed_special, model_kwargs) parameters as values:
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings

        embeddings_model = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
            deployment=<'deployment_name'>
            model='gpt_35_turbo',
            openai_api_type="azure", 
            values=model_config,
        )

Then I call Redis.from_documents() to generate embeddings as follow:
from langchain_community.vectorstores.redis import Redis

Redis.from_documents(
                    docs,  # a list of Document objects from loaders or created
                    embeddings_model,
                    redis_url=redis_url,
                    index_name=redis_index_name,
                )

It fails with the following error:
TypeError: Embeddings.create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'values'

On my second try to fix this issue, I tried to create the embedding model as follow:
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings

  "model_config": {
    "allowed_special": "",
    "chunk_size": 50,
    "disallowed_special": "all",
    "embedding_ctx_length": 8191,
    "generation_max_tokens": 8000,
    "model_kwargs": ""
  }
        embeddings_model = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
            deployment=<'deployment_name'>
            model='gpt_35_turbo',
            openai_api_type="azure", 
            **self.__model_config,
        )

then it doesn't handle the cases if model_kwargs is not set:
>       invalid_model_kwargs = all_required_field_names.intersection(extra.keys())
E       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_openai/embeddings/base.py:219: AttributeError

Any suggestion on how to fix the issue? Here are the packages version I'm using:
langchain                 0.2.3
langchain-community       0.2.4
langchain-core            0.2.5
langchain-openai          0.1.14
langchain-text-splitters  0.2.1


You seem to be mixing various families of models and the parameters to use them.
If you want to generate embeddings, you cannot use a GPT-3.5 model or any GPT-family model: you need to use other models like text-embedding-ada-002 or text-embedding-3-large for example (see list here for Azure OpenAI)

And you will not have parameters like "max_tokens" for those models, as they have a fixed-size output: text-embedding-ada-002 will generate an array of 1536 numeric values, even if your input is only 1 token.
Regarding embedding_ctx_length parameter, it is an helper in Langchain to avoid raising error when you send an input with a token count higher than the  max input of the model used. If you exceed this amount, it will split your input (see info).

Please note that all 3 embeddings models mentioned previously have a max input size at 8191 tokens (see openai doc):

